# Install CD for Xubuntu hangs, should I remove the wire from my sda hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, xubuntu

I'm trying to install 32bit x86 Xubuntu on sdb. sda has grub, W2000 and Fedora-3. Install CD live session works like a charm (this is why I chose Xubuntu based on previous experience with it on USB stick live session and frustration with another distro), but my install fails.

Install CD hangs if I choose "Install" option in opening screen. If I double-click on install CD in live session it, gets to the point of asking me to unmount or not sda. Regardless of my answer it hangs anyway.

I tried it with sdb partitioned and no ext filesystem created and with ext3 filesystem created, at least 6Gb.

I would like to install Xubuntu on sdb1 (6Gb of ext3) and use my existing grub on sda to choose to boot to Xubuntu on sdb1. I have no problem installing grub on sdb MBR and choosing BIOS boot to sda grub or sdb grub. The main thing is that I'd like to leave sda alone.

Would a brute force approach of pulling the wire off from sda hard drive and using the Xubuntu install CD work? Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Don't know why it hangs, but as a workaround, consider installing a previous version and upgrading after installation. If applicable, another option is to install on sdb from within a virtual machine that has an unused sda virtual disk.

Comment: Consider launching the installer `ubiquity` from a terminal, redirecting the output to a file, so this might give you an error log. (Again, consider doing it in a virtual machine, to avoid messing sda with a non-clean unmount.) When it hangs, press Ctrl+Alt+F1: if a terminal prompt appears, run the command `dmesg | tail`, this could give you more information.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions. Brute force did not work, but installing previous version and upgrading did. Now I have a functioning Xubuntu.

ubuquity reported illegal something, so it did not help to pinpoint the problem. But installing previous version did.